# Concepts of left group and right group.

Tags: group-theory

I have somewhere the concepts of **left groups** (A non empty set with an associative binary operation, a left identity and each element has left inverse) and **right groups**. I have also studied some basic properties of identities and inverses [here](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9788132215981-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1432815-p175373305).

Now I have a question.

Does there exist a left group which is not right group?

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer, so I thought I should point this out so that others do not make the same mistake. Injective functions have right-inverses, but the inverses are left-invertible (they are surjections). Similarly, surjections have left-inverses, which are injections. In general, an operation which yields *either* a left group *or* a right group is actually a group.

Comment: (That should be, "I made a mistake in my answers *and I have now fixed it*".)

Comment: The usual definition of a right and left group are different. They require either left identity and right inverses, or right inverses and left idenity. Those are actually products of a group and a left/right zero semigroup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A set under an operation $(S, \ast)$ which is *either* a left group *or* a right group is actually a group. I'll prove this for left groups. The right-group proof is analogous.

Let $s\in S$ be arbitrary, and write $1$ for the left-identity. Then $s$ has a left-inverse $t$. We prove that $st=1$. We have the following.
$$stst=s(ts)t=st$$
Then $st$ has a left-inverse, and multiplying both sides of $stst=st$ by this we see that $st=1$ as required. Therefore, we have two-sided inverses.

It now suffices to prove that $s\ast1=s$ (where $s$ is arbitrary). This follows from the following.
$$s=(st)\ast s=sts=s\ast(ts)=s\ast1$$
The proof is complete.

Answer (score 4):

In fact a left group is a group and so is a right group. The lemmas below, which I have cut and pasted from some lecture notes, prove this.

Definition. A *left group* is a set $G$ together with a binary operation $\circ: G \times G
\rightarrow G$ that satisfies the following properties:

(i) For all $g,h \in G$, $g \circ h \in G$;

(ii) For all $g,h,k \in G$, $(g \circ h) \circ k = g \circ (h \circ k)$;

(iii) There exists an element $e \in G$, called a *left identity element*, such that:

(a)  for all $g \in G$, $e \circ g = g$; and

(b)  for all $g \in G$ there exists $h \in G$ (a *left inverse* of $g$) such that $h \circ g = e$.

Lemma 1. Let $G$ be a left group, let $e \in G$ be a left identity
element, and for $g \in G$, let $h \in G$ be a left inverse element of $g$.
Then $g \circ e = g$ and $g \circ h = e$ (i.e. $e$ is also a right inverse element and $h$ is also a right inverse of $g$).

Proof. We have $h \circ (g \circ e)  = (h \circ g) \circ e = e \circ e =
e = h \circ g.$ Now let $h'$ be an inverse of $h$. Then multiplying the
left and right sides of this equation on the left by $h'$ and using
associativity gives
$(h' \circ h) \circ (g \circ e) = (h' \circ h) \circ g$. But
$(h' \circ h) \circ (g \circ e) = e \circ (g \circ e) = g \circ e$, and
$(h' \circ h) \circ g = e \circ g = g$, so we get $g \circ e = g$.

We have
$h \circ (g \circ h) = (h \circ g) \circ h = e \circ h = h$, and multiplying
on the left by $h'$ gives
$(h' \circ h) \circ (g \circ h) = h' \circ h$.
But $(h' \circ h) \circ (g \circ h) = e \circ (g \circ h) = g \circ h$
and $(h' \circ h)  = e$, so $g \circ h = e$.

Lemma 2. Let $G$ be a left group. Then $G$ has a unique identity element,
and any $g \in G$ has a unique inverse.

Proof. Let $e$ and $f$ be two identity elements of $G$. Then, $e \circ f = f$,
but by Lemma 1, we also have $e \circ f = e$, so $e=f$ and
the identity element is unique.

Let $h$ and $h'$ be two inverses for $g$. Then $h \circ g = h' \circ g = e$,
but by Lemma 1 we also have $g \circ h = e$, so
$$h = e \circ h = (h' \circ g) \circ h = h' \circ (g \circ h) = h' \circ e = h'$$
and the inverse of $g$ is unique.